# Compare two xml sql query DB2

Tags: sql, xml, db2

I have two tables in the database. Both have ID, name1. Name1 is an XML data type.
Does anyone know of any possibility to compare the contents of these two xml?

`select * from table1 t join table2 b on t.ID = b.ID where t.name1 <> b.name1`

But it doesn't work. I get

`SQL Error [42818]: The data types of the operands for the operation "<>" are not compatible or comparable.. SQLCODE=-401, SQLSTATE=42818, DRIVER=4.21.29`

Answer (score 0):

You can compare a `VARCHAR` version of the two XML values using [`XMLSERIALIZE`](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0022194.html):

```sql
select * 
from table1 t 
join table2 b on t.ID = b.ID 
where xmlserialize(t.name1 as varchar(32672)) 
   <> xmlserialize(b.name1 as varchar(32672))
```